# PhpStorm Run Configuration executes without testing webpage

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

For a PHP project, I set up a project and a **Run Configuration**, but when I run the project (`Run > Run`):

1. The browser opens on XAMPP
2. The browser is redirected to myserver/mypage
3. ...but the page is missing (404)

The issue is that **Run Configuration** doesn't work properly with the project files. (I don't know if files should be copied to xampp folder or Run should work in-memory). I set also a debug configuration with Zend.

I got the same issue with `Run > Run` or `Run > Debug`.

What I have done:

1. Set XAMPP as a local server

   1. XAMPP is tested and working;
2. Setup the XAMPP server on PhpStorm (that is: same computer, different folder from project);
3. Created a project of 1 file: `phpinfo.php`;
4. Set up a **Run Configuration** (`Run > Configurations...`) which corresponds project folder with xampp folder;
5. Set up **Zend Debug** as PHP Debugger;

   1. Debug configuration is validated with `Run > Validate debug Configuration`

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials ; in particular: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE

Comment: I’ve followed tutorials for installing both XAMPP and Zend Debug, and I can’t find what mistake I have done. Preference > Deployment > Test is ok, and Run > Web Server Debug Validation is ok. There is any specific test you suggest?

Comment: Should the build in Server (Preference > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger) be used also in PHP run/debug configurations? I noticed that when I run a Javascript Run Configuration the build-in server is used, but it not happens when I run a PHP Run Configuration